# flutter doctor cannot execute AdoptOpenJDK to determine the version

Tags: java, android, windows, sdk, flutter-doctor

I followed every step for flutter installation but my flutter doctor cannot execute AdoptOpenJDK to determine the version.

Following Error occurs

[image]

I already checked my Path Variables and my JavaHome for the right directory  "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-15.0.1.9-hotspot\bin\java.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Home needs to point to the directory with the bin folder, not to the executable itself.

Reread the instructions